# Restart Mac without it automatically mounting additional AFPS containers (that exist on the internal drive)

Tags: disk-utility, restart, automount

I have two extra AFPS containers on my (4TB) MacBook Pro internal drive. These containers/volumes hold large archives that cause some issues if left mounted, so I keep them unmounted when not in active use. However, each time I restart the computer they auto mount and I have to unmount them again manually. Is there a way to set such containers/volumes to *not mount* when the computer is restarted? I would mount them manually from Disk Utility when I need them available.

Comment: Did this answer help https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/236105/prevent-internal-drive-from-mounting-automatically?

Comment: Or these https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310574/how-to-prevent-auto-mounting-of-a-volume-in-macos-high-sierra https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120782/how-to-disable-usb-auto-mount?

Comment: These links were very helpful. I followed the instructions for editing the /ect/fstab file from this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310574/how-to-prevent-auto-mounting-of-a-volume-in-macos-high-sierra and this solved the problem for me (on Ventura).